# Series internal resistance of Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, internal-resistance

I have this power supply - [GPC-3030D](http://farnell.com/datasheets/1789646.pdf?_ga=2.82647190.1290543250.1590506495-1897769628.1590506495)

There are 3 independent channels. 2x (30V/3A) and 1x (5V/3A)

To find the internal resistance of the voltage source channels, its just 30V/3A = 10Ohms and 5V/3A = 1.66Ohms.

Is it correct?

Comment: Eh. No.  If that were the internal resistance, then a load of 3A would cause the output voltage to drop drastically.

Comment: Ideal voltage sources have zero internal resistance - the current drawn is solely due to the external load. A real voltage source should have an extremely low internal resistance - else it wouldn't regulate properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can estimate the effective internal resistance of the outputs from the load regulation specification.

For the fixed 5 V output, it's given as <10 mV.

If the output voltage drops by 10 mV for a change in output current of 3 A, then the output resistance is \$\frac{10 mV}{ 3 A}\$ <= 3 mΩ.

Comment: When you say the output voltage drops by 10mV, are you meaning 5V dropping to 4.99V ? At that time, if the output current is 3A, then the internal resistance is 3mohm. What if the output currents is different and could you please explain what does the datasheet mean when it says  "for 5Voutput, less than 10mV ". Please tell me how are you figuring it out from the start. I am just trying to understand the concept

Comment: Could you please tell me how to read the load regulation specification and from where are you taking this value in the datasheet? (in the constant voltage section or in the constant current section?

Comment: @Newbie   The load regulation specification I have quoted is from the '5 V fixed output' section, 'load regulation' line. For the adjustable outputs, you'd use the 'constant voltage' section, and read the 'load regulation' lines. They're a bit more complicated, as the output voltage is settable. So for the <=10 A line, you read 0.01% + 5mV. If you set 20 V output, then the specified droop would be 5 mV + 0.01%*20 = 5 mV + 2 mV = 7 mV. How to use it is shown by example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A good bench power supply might produce 30 volts on its output terminals over a wide load current range and then, if the current exceeded the maximum limit it would turn off. Like this: -

[image]

So, up to a limit of 3 amps, the voltage reduces by only 1 mV and that would imply a series resistance of 300 μΩ or 0.3 mΩ or 0.0003 Ω.

Above the maximum current limit, the voltage would fall rapidly to zero.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for bothering with constant questions. But I'm finding difficulty in understanding the concepts. 1. From when did you take the above graph and how is the value of 30V, 3A and 1mV considered? 2. In constant current mode ans in constant voltage mode, the series resistance of the PSU will be the same or different?

Comment: I just drew the graph on the basis of what I know about bench power supplies. A bench power supply is intended to deliver the dialed-in output voltage across all load currents hence, it might be expected to remain at 30 volts +/- 1 mV. I expect that if it was 30 volts +/- 10 mV it wouldn't be a big deal but someone, somewhere will want a regulation as tight as 1 mV in 30 volts at currents up to 3 amps. Your power supply is stated as having a regulation of +/- 0.01% up to 3 amps hence it would likely droop by 3 mV under full load conditions.

Comment: Ok. So you have considered the load regulation parameter in the constant voltage section only right? At what case do we need to consider the load regulation in the constant current parameter?

Comment: When the bench power supply switches (usually seamlessly and without the user noticing) from CV to CC operation.

Answer (score 1):

> To find the internal resistance of the voltage source channels, its just 30V/3A = 10 ohms and 5V/3A = 1.66 ohms.

Niel has answered your question. I'll explain the problem with your thought process.

If the internal resistance of the 30 V / 3 A PSU is 10 Ω then calculate the voltage drop when 3 A is being supplied. This will be \$ V = IR = 3 \times 10 = 30 \ \text V \$. This means that you have nothing left! All 30 V is dropped across the internal resistor.

This is a mistake made by many beginners when working out the capacity of a PSU or battery. They'll measure the voltage - let's say it's 12 V - and then short it out with the multimeter on A-DC range and measure the current. If the meter survives they then take the reading - let's say 8 A - and calculate that the battery is capable of \$ P = VI = 12 \times 8 = 96 \ \text W \$. What they have forgotten is that if they had done the test with a voltmeter and ammeter at the same time they would have 8 A but 0 V due to the dead short. \$ P = VI = 0 \times 8 = 0 \ \text W \$. All the power would be dissipated in the battery and none in the load.

In general you shouldn't short out batteries.

---

[image]

*Figure 1. The power supply in question.*

This changes the question a bit as this is a high-spec laboratory power supply.

> If that's the wrong way to measure the capacity of the PSU, which is the correct way?

This power supply has the ability to set voltage and current limits using the controls on the front panel.

- Let's say we set it to 12 V and 1.2 A maximum. With no load attached the voltage will rise to 12 V and the CV (constant voltage) LED will turn on.
- Now we connect up a 20 Ω resistor to the terminals. The current will rise to 0.6 A but we haven't exceeded the 1.2 A limit yet so the PSU will remain in CV mode.
- As we increase the load by decreasing the resistance to 10 Ω we will see at some point (exactly 10 Ω if everything is calibrated correctly) the CV and CC (constant current) LEDs will begin to flicker. The meters will read 12 V and 1.2 A.
- If we decrease the resistance further the CV indicator will turn off and the CC indicator will turn on.
- If we decrease the resistance to 5 Ω the current will remain limited to 1.2 A but the voltage will decrease to 6 V.

> And could you also please tell me how to read the load regulation specification and from where are you taking this value in the datasheet? (in the constant voltage section or in the constant current section?

You use the value for the mode you are operating in. If the CV indicator is on then use the Constant Voltage specifications. If the CC indicator is on then use the Constant Current specifications.

---

This power supply is "regulated". That means it monitors the output voltage (or current) and adjusts the output to match the setpoints you have chosen. If the load causes the voltage to sag a little the PSU will "open-up" the output transistors enough to bring the output back to the setpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If that's the wrong way to measure the capacity of the PSU, which is the correct way? And Could you also please tell me how to read the load regulation specification and from where are you taking this value in the datasheet? (in the constant voltage section or in the constant current section? I am trying to understand the concept

Comment: Pick a PSU datasheet and add it to your question and we'll have a look.

Comment: I have added my PSU specification sheet in my question. That's good?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: CONSTANT VOLTAGE OPERATION
Line regulation 0.01% + 3mV  - this means max. error of regulation. For 10V for example: 10V*0.01/100=1mV+3mV = 4mV max. absolute error of regulation.
   Similar for current regulation.